# Xamarin.Essentials causes crash in Xamarin.Forms.macOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building a Xamarin.Forms.MacOS app after following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=windows%2Cios

In this app, I want to use Xamarin.Essentials. I can successfully add this package to my macOS projcet but during launch I am hit with the following error message:

`This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.`

I have tried to add the code snippet:

`Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);`

In the `public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)` method in the `AppDelegate` file in macOS, but it has an issue finding the reference of `.Platform`.

How do i make Xamarin.Essentials work for macOS for Xamarin forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin.Essentials does **not** currently support macOS. This has been an open issue since 2018 as there is no official sponsor of that platform nor Linux, WinForms, etc...

```
iOS - Supported By Microsoft
Android - Supported By Microsoft
UWP - Supported By Microsoft
macOS
WinForms/WPF
GTK#
Tizen - Supported by Samsung
watchOS - Supported By Microsoft
tvOS - Supported By Microsoft
```

**Additional Platform Support #662**

- https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/662

**macOS support #111**

- https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/111

Note: This might change in the v1.6 release of Essentials, but it is still not listed on the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/platform-feature-support

Note: There are "unofficial" forks that provide fairly complete support of macOS, you will need to clone, possibly merge w/ the official repo and build it yourself. Review the above github issues for the personal forks that support macOS.

Comment: Well noted. Thanks a lot for the info and links. Do you know if there are any guides on how i can get my xamarin versions to these unofficial forks? Can i do it by clicking "Show pre release packages" and adding a future nuget version?

Comment: @DiddanDo No, there are no official "pre release packages" of  Essentials that support macOS as no PR supporting macOS has been merged yet. This "might" be happen in the v1.6 release, but resources for macOS from MS/Xamarin have been lacking for years as Xamarin.Mac has such a small dev/user base.

Comment: @DiddanDo Guides? You can follow the readme and the build script in the official repo (https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials) to get started on building the official repo first and then merge this PR as a start to adding macOS    https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/pull/653 (review the PR comments to see which features are currently supported).